# Not able to clone Github repo using jgit api getting invalid Remote Exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, github, jgit

Not able to clone Github repo using jgit api getting invalid Remote Exception. I am getting this error when i am running test cases using docker in spring boot.In actual code it is working fine not giving any error but when i run test case for the same method i got org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.InvalidRemoteException: Invalid remote: origin  exception full stack trace is given below.

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.InvalidRemoteException: Invalid remote: origin
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:221)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:182)
        at com.appscms.alchemist.utils.GitUtility.cloneRepo(GitUtility.java:80)
        at com.appscms.alchemist.service.AppBuildingService.createApp(AppBuildingService.java:167)
        at com.appscms.alchemist.service.AppBuildingService.createAppRequest(AppBuildingService.java:160)
        at com.appscms.alchemist.controller.AppController.build(AppController.java:115)
        at com.appscms.alchemist.controller.DeliveryDetailControllerTests.shouldCreateBuild(DeliveryDetailControllerTests.java:93)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
    Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoRemoteRepositoryException: http://github.com*******.git: https://github.com*****.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: Not Found
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.createNotFoundException(TransportHttp.java:600)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:668)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:465)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:142)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:94)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1309)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:213)
        
    
     public Git cloneRepo() throws InvalidRemoteException, TransportException, GitAPIException, IOException {
        var staticDir = new File(GithubConstants.path);
        if(staticDir.isDirectory()) {
            org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(staticDir);
        }
        staticDir.mkdir();
        return Git.cloneRepository()
        .setURI(GithubConstants.cloneUrl)
        .setDirectory(staticDir)
        .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(githubAccessDto.getUsername(), github
    `AccessDto.getPassword()))
        .call();
    
    }`
```

Comment: What is the value of `GithubConstants.cloneUrl`?  The URL given in the exception message starts with `http://github.com...`. Shouldn't it be `https://...`? I'm not sure that JGit will follow redirects.

Comment: it is https:// by mistake i have removed the 's' while removing the actual url of repository from stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

The "Invalid remote: origin" exception is a catch all generic exception that doesn't tell you what the underlying cause is.

If you scroll down the stack trace, there's an exception for the underlying problem:

Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoRemoteRepositoryException: http://github.com*******.git: https://github.com*****.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: Not Found

I think you may need to access GitHub using SSH and setup a public and private RSA key.